# Comparing rapidly-changing string values to find frequent occurrences

Tags: c#

My problem should be quite simple. I have a random generated string that changes multiple times per second. I want to return 1  **if it appears x times consecutively**.

My current code:

```
string s; //this is the generated string
int checker = 0;
string[] s_list = null;

if( cheaker == 0)
{
s_list[0] = s;
}
else if( cheaker == 1)
{
s_list[1] = s;
}
checker++;

if(s_list[0] == s_list[1])  return 1;
```

My problem is that I want to be able to change the amount of x times if appears and like this it will generate tons of code if the x is too big.

**Do you think putting the current string into an array of string and compare them is the best way? There should be a better implementation.**

Comment: You need a `for` loop. Or a regex.

Comment: The part of the code that's *complicated* is the part you're not showing/glossing over. How are you going to check a string whose value changes 30 times per second? Is this code in a method that you're calling each time the string changes? If so, the `checker` value will need to be `static` or raised to a higher scope.

Comment: this code is inside a timer.

Comment: Do you think putting the current string into an array of string and compare them is the best way? There should be a better implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the code generic for any given X, you should keep last X strings and check whether all they are equal, e.g.:

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    if (list.Count >= X)
    {
        list.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    list.Add(newString);

    return list.Count >= X && list.Any(s => s == list[0]);
```

Comment: It checks whether the list gathered enough data (X strings) and then using LINQ it checks whether all the strings in the list are equal (we could check it by comparing all the strings with first one).

Comment: good implementation. and short code. THis should work. Thanks ;)

Answer (score -1):

I assume s_list is an array where you store all the generations of the string

```
string s;
string[] s_list;

// Your logic that would generate s and store it in s_list
// ...
// ...

int required_amount = 10; // whatever X amount you want
int current_sequence = 0;

// It's important to start at 1, and not 0,
// as you compare to the previous entry each time
for(int i = 1; i < s_list.Lenght; i++ )
{
   if( s_list[i] == s_list[i-1] )
   {
     current_sequence++;
     if(current_sequence >= required_amount)
     {
       return 1;
     }
   }
   else
   {
     current_sequence = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: The list of strings should be rolled, new strings (over X) should displace old, so that only X last strings are checked.

Comment: Thx this is good i think. Do you know a better way to put the received string s into the s_list without creating multiple ifs and else ifs and incrementing the checker?

Comment: @CodeFuller Tiago is obviously at a beginner level. I know 10 other ways to do this better; this is about making it in a way that he can understand.